# shadow box not filling page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a background image and a black shadow box overlaying (inline)  covering it to darken the image, however on mobile devices the footer div goes outside of the body tag. While the background still renders and stretches to the page, the shadow box doesn't extend all the way.

any help is greatly appreciated

html:

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid external-sites">
            <div class="flex-parent">
                <div class="flex-child child-1">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrew-waller-
  b66180146" target="_blank">
                        <div class="box">
                            <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-child child-2">
                    <a href="https://github.com/Adrw4" target="_blank">
                        <div class="box">
                            <i class="fa fa-github-square fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-child child-3">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/adrw4/?hl=en" 
 target="_blank">
                        <div class="box">
                            <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-child child-4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="box">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-html5 fa-5x 
   fa-center"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
   body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width:100;
    }

    body,
    html {
    background: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/circuit-board.jpg");
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    content: '';
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10000px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    }


    .text-box {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-style: oblique;
    }

   .box {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
   }

   .external-sites {
    height: 25%;
    overflow: auto;
    }

   .flex-parent {
    list-style: none;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .flex-child {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 2px;
   }
.child-1 {
    order: 1;
}

.child-2 {
    order: 2;
}

.child-3 {
    order: 3;
}

.child-4 {
    order: 4;   
}

/*==============================================================================external sites==*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 830px) {
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .flex-child {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more than likely an issue with your body/html styles. Try correcting the body 'width: 100' to either 'width: 100%' or a fixed width, depending on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browser support that you need (no Edge & IE), you could set a background color to a dark gray, and use `background-blend-mode` instead of using a giant `box-shadow`.

```
body {
  background-color: #444;
  background-image: url(..img/yourImage.jpg);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Just don't use black as the `background-color` or you won't see your image. Control how dark it is by changing the color.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem instantly